# What is the difference between using [..., :<number>] and [:<number>] on a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

In practice, using both `[..., :2]` and `[:2]` on `np.array([1,2,3])` results in `np.array([1,2])`. Are there also cases where the result differs when you use an ellipsis like this on an array?

Comment: ``np.array([[1,2,3]])``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

np.arrays are designed to handle n-dimensional arrays, specified as `[rows, columns]`In the case of `np.array([1, 2, 3])`, `[:2]` and `[:, :2]` will yield the same result because our array input is 1-dimensional of shape `[1, 3]`, e.g. with 1 row and 3 columns.

If we instead input `np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])`, e.g. a 2-dimensional array of shape `[2, 3]`, this will change. On this array, if we, e.g., do `[:1, :2]` we will get `array([[1, 2]])` because we are asking for everything up to the first (i.e. the 2nd since we count from zero) row and everything up to the second (i.e. the 3rd) column.

Hope this makes sense.